# How to call Tcl command with conditional option

Tags: conditional-statements, command, tcl

I want to conditionally append options when calling a Tcl command. I'm using a Xilinx Tcl command synth_design as indicated in [UG835](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_4/ug835-vivado-tcl-commands.pdf) p.1042 using Tcl version 8.5.

For instance, I want to:

1. build a data structure that will append 0 or more of `-verilog_define MACRO` where `-verilog_define` is not a string but an option, and
2. pass that structure to the command in its expanded form.

Where this:

```
synth_design -top ${top}_top -part ${part} -verilog_define MACRO1 -verilog_define MACRO2
                                           ^-------------------------------------------^
```

Becomes this:

```
synth_design -top ${top}_top -part ${part} ???
                                           ^-^
```

Comment: If you're on a Tcl version before 8.5, you would use `eval synth_design -top ${top}_top -part ${part} $options`

Comment: Strictly, `eval [list synth_design -top ${top}_top -part ${part}] $options` to avoid problems if `$top` or `$part` contain Tcl metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

With `{*}$makro` (expansion)

E.g.:

```
set makro {-verilog_define MACRO1 -verilog_define MACRO2}
synth_design -top ${top}_top -part ${part} {*}$makro
```

Comment: Ok what if MACRO is a string
`set defs {}`

`array set options $::argv`

`set git_ver $options(-git_ver)`

`lappend defs {-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}}`

`foreach i $defs { puts $i }` ... this gives me `-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}`

Comment: You are using `lappend` probably wrong. Try `lappend defs -verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}`