# How to get string in Tcl expansion substitution

Tags: string, tcl, expansion

To follow up with an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169533/how-to-call-tcl-command-with-conditional-option) question using Tcl version 8.5 I have:

```
set defs {}
array set options $::argv
set git_ver $options(-git_ver)
lappend defs {-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}}
foreach i $defs { puts $i }
```

What I get from puts is:

```
-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}
```

But how do I get the string representation of my variable git_ver?

Comment: Do `lappend defs "-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}"` instead? That will substitute the variable when you append the string to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of braces:

```
lappend defs "-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}"
```

Alternatively you can use the `subst` command to make braces act like double quotes:

```
lappend defs [subst {-verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}}]
```

In Tcl, double quotes and braces do the same thing - group words. The only difference is that double quotes perform substitutions and braces don't.

Comment: The final alternative is `lappend defs [list -verilog_define GIT_VERSION=${git_ver}]` but I'd guess that `git_ver` contains something “nice” and free of metasyntax characters…